# Mongoose Populate Cast Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the follwing schemas:

```
// online.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Online Friends
var onlineSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userid:{ type: Number, ref:'Player' }
},{timestamps : true});


// Export

module.exports = mongoose.model('Online', onlineSchema);


//player.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for player data
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userid    : { type: Number, required: true,unique:true, default: 0 },
  firstname    : { type: String },
  nick : {type: String, required: true},
  lastname : {type: String},
  lastupdate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},{timestamps : true});


// create the model and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);


//main.js
...
const Online = require('./config/models/online.js');
const Player = require('./config/models/player.js');

Online.find({userid:3441341}).populate('userid').exec(function(err,result){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});

...
```

I want to search Online for a userid and then print the name of the user, not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.
This is the error I'm getting:

```
MongooseError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "3441341" at path "_id"
```

What is the proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you show your other models as well?

Comment: These 2 are the only ones that intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the userid type from `Number` to `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` and it should work. It basically says you are trying to cast a number to Object Id. Pass the ids as strings.
In NoSQL DBS your documents must have _id field. Do you have a User model or do you use Player for the job? If you use Player as User model so change user_id to _id

Comment: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1299304" at path "userid" for model "Online"'. I'm assining userid a number, shouldnt the type be Number ?

Comment: Did you try changing the userid types from Number to mongoose.Schema.ObjectId ?

Comment: Pass the ids as strings not as numbers.

Comment: In NoSQL DBS your documents must have _id field. Do you have a User model or do you use Player for the job? If you use Player as User model so change user_id to _id.